# Netlogo - working with nested breed

Tags: netlogo

I have a breed of turtle that owns another breed of turtle.
I need to do something like:

```
 set my-turtle-set breed1 "owned by" breed2 with [some-attribute = 1]
```

So i need to put in a turtleset some turtle of the breed1 if they are owned by the turtle of the breed 2 with some characteristic.

### Clarifying

Maybe thre was a misunderstanding:

I have already the breed2 owning the breed1:

```
breed2-own [my-owner]
```

and i can correctly put my breed1 turtles inside my breed2 turtles.

The problem is that i need to make hidden? some breed1 turtles basing on who onws them.
SO updating to the example (i remove my-turtle-set for being more clear):

```
ask breed1 ("owned by" breed2 with [some-attribute = 1]) [set hidden? true]
```

So the turtles already own correctly the other breed just i dont know, given a breed1 tutle, how to call its ower.
for this reason i need something like "owned by".

### To Clarify even more

I have the breed2 that are part of a tree (network). At every step i set an attribute leaf? true to the leaf.

now each breed2 owns a breed1 and to every turn I need to set hidden? false toe the breed1 which are not onwed by a leaf, instead to set hidden? true to the breed1 which are owned by a leaf

Comment: Is this your question?:  How do I call `set hidden? true` in each `breed1` for which there is some `breed2` that owns it?

Comment: Quite. Each breed2 have one (not more and not less) beed1 turtle.
My question is how I call set hidden? true in each breed1 for which his breed2 has some-attribute = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `breed2` is the breed that owns, then this line:

```
breed2-own [my-owner]
```

doesn't make sense; the wording implies the relationship goes in the other direction. I'll assume you mean:

```
breed2-own [owned]
```

Then one way to solve your problem is:

```
ask breed1 [
  set hidden? any? breed2 with [owned = myself]
]
```

If the number of agents in your model is fairly small, this should be fine.

If you have lots of agents, then you may start having speed problems, because in the above code, each `breed1` does its own independent search through all `breed2` agents.

Two possible ways to fix that:

1. Do what Mars suggests in his answer.
2. Get rid of the `owned` variable altogether, and use links to represent the owning relationships.

Comment: What will make the model faster?

-Do what Mars suggests in his answer.
-Get rid of the owned variable altogether, and use links to represent the owning relationships.

Comment: How many breed2s does a typical breed1 own? If the answer is "a handful", I don't know which way would be faster. If the answer is more like "a hundred", I'd expect links to win, especially if you frequently create and destroy agents and ownership relationships. But, I'm only making rough guesses.

Comment: I'd say much more than 100 (worst case 10898 turtles for now). each breed2 owns always 1 (not more and not less) breed1 and i never destroy relationship between them.
In a future version ill need that each breed1 will own a breed0.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving the owner breed a `turtles-own` variable that stores turtle-set containing the turtles it owns?  You can also store a reference to the owner in each `breed1`, if that will make the code that uses this information simpler.

```
breed1-own [my-owner]
breed2-own [my-owned]    
...
ask breed2 with [some-attribute = 1]
 [set my-owned my-turtle-set
  ask my-turtle-set [set my-owner myself]
```

Here `myself` refers to the `breed2` turtle from the outer `ask`.  (If you used `self`, instead, that would refer to the `breed1` turtle from the inner `ask`.)

(Don't use both kinds of references unless you need both, though, because having `breed1`s and `breed2`s refer to each other means that when your code changes references of one kind, it has to change corresponding references of the other kind as well.)

Comment: OK.  General advice: Try to make the question clearer at the beginning. I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking.  So if I answer, I'd be guessing again.  The new question you asked doesn't sound anything like your original question.

Comment: Quite. Each breed2 have one (not more and not less) beed1 turtle. My question is how I call set hidden? true in each breed1 for which his breed2 has some-attribute = 1

Comment: like this: `ask breed1 [ set hidden? (my-owner != nobody) and [some-attribute = 1] of my-owner ]`